# Python - search for a specific value in an array

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm using `Python` and `requests` library to call an `API` in order to get some information. So far so good. The code is working fine and the response is successful:

**Request:**

```
def countries():
    # Application header
    header = {
        'Authorization': '123456789',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'b4ed4ab7ebe84f0db79d42633771b741'
    }
    # Make the request and return the country code
    request_url = requests.get(
        'https://endpoint/api/Countries', headers=header)

    countries_dictionary = request_url.json()

countries()
```

I store the response into a variable and encoding it into `JSON`. When I print the value of my variable the result is like:

**Code:**

```
print(countries_dictionary)
```

**Response:**

```
[
{'CountryId': 1, 'CountryName': 'Belgium', 'Abbreviation': 'B'}, 
...............................................................
...............................................................
{'CountryId': 26, 'CountryName': 'Great Britain', 'Abbreviation': 'GB'}
]
```

Based on the result that starts with brackets, the response is a list. According to the equivalents between `Python` and `JSON` a list is translated to be an array. However, if I would like to extract the value of the first key, I get an error saying that:

**Code**

```
for country in countries_dictionary['CountryId'][0]:
    if country['CountryId']=='1':
        print('Test')
```

**Error:**

> File "c:/Python 3.7/api.py", line 49, in countries
>       for country in countries_dictionary['CountryId']:
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

I understand that the index is represented by an integer data type and since the response I get does not have any parent node I am a bit lost and don't know how to proceed next. Whatever I have found so far on Stackoverflow or any other website didn't do the trick. Any tips?

**EDIT:**

```
[
{'CountryId': 1, 'CountryName': 'Romania', 'Abbreviation': 'RO'}, 
{'CountryId': 2, 'CountryName': 'Bulgaria', 'Abbreviation': 'BG'}, 
{'CountryId': 3, 'CountryName': 'Slovenia', 'Abbreviation': 'SI'}, 
{'CountryId': 4, 'CountryName': 'Olanda', 'Abbreviation': 'NL'}, 
{'CountryId': 5, 'CountryName': 'Polonia', 'Abbreviation': 'PL'}, 
{'CountryId': 6, 'CountryName': 'Belgia', 'Abbreviation': 'BE'}, 
{'CountryId': 7, 'CountryName': 'Germania', 'Abbreviation': 'DE'}, 
{'CountryId': 8, 'CountryName': 'Spania', 'Abbreviation': 'ES'}, 
{'CountryId': 9, 'CountryName': 'Portugalia', 'Abbreviation': 'PT'}, 
{'CountryId': 10, 'CountryName': 'Irlanda', 'Abbreviation': 'IE'}, 
{'CountryId': 11, 'CountryName': 'Austria', 'Abbreviation': 'AT'}, 
{'CountryId': 12, 'CountryName': 'Croatia', 'Abbreviation': 'HR'}, 
{'CountryId': 13, 'CountryName': 'Ungaria', 'Abbreviation': 'HU'}, 
{'CountryId': 14, 'CountryName': 'Suedia', 'Abbreviation': 'SE'}, 
{'CountryId': 15, 'CountryName': 'Slovacia', 'Abbreviation': 'SK'},
{'CountryId': 16, 'CountryName': 'Cehia', 'Abbreviation': 'CZ'}, 
{'CountryId': 17, 'CountryName': 'Danemarca', 'Abbreviation': 'DK'}, 
{'CountryId': 18, 'CountryName': 'Estonia', 'Abbreviation': 'EE'}, 
{'CountryId': 19, 'CountryName': 'Finlanda', 'Abbreviation': 'FI'}, 
{'CountryId': 20, 'CountryName': 'Franta', 'Abbreviation': 'FR'}, 
{'CountryId': 21, 'CountryName': 'Letonia', 'Abbreviation': 'LV'}, 
{'CountryId': 22, 'CountryName': 'Lituania', 'Abbreviation': 'LT'}, 
{'CountryId': 23, 'CountryName': 'Luxemburg', 'Abbreviation': 'LU'}, 
{'CountryId': 24, 'CountryName': 'Norvegia', 'Abbreviation': 'NO'}, 
{'CountryId': 25, 'CountryName': 'Marea Britanie', 'Abbreviation': 'GB'}, 
{'CountryId': 26, 'CountryName': 'Ucraina', 'Abbreviation': 'UA'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample list of your dictionary, you had a couple errors in your code

- you don't need the [0] index because you're looping through the list
- you can't specify the ['CountryId'] in the for loop definition
- the dictionary values for ['CountryId'] are integers, not strings

  but this should do the trick

```
countries_dictionary = [{'CountryId': 1, 'CountryName': 'Belgium', 'Abbreviation': 'B'}, 
                        {'CountryId': 26, 'CountryName': 'Great Britain', 'Abbreviation': 'GB'}]
for country in countries_dictionary:
    if country['CountryId']==1:
        print('Test')
```

Comment: Same error man: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: @cdrrr can you add more of the dictionary then? Because it's working with that small sample.

Comment: @cdrrr Are you sure you typed it in correctly? His code should work. You iterate over the dicts in the list, and then you access the dict's `CountryId` property. There should be no place you are trying to access a string indices.

Comment: You mean the whole response?

Comment: @cdrrr yes, adding the whole response to your question would be helpful

Comment: @cdrrr okay, then my code definitely works with that dictionary. Can you post the error you're getting when you use my code?

Comment: Now it works. Don't know why. However, it would like to print the value of the key, which is the number, not the string test. How can I do it?

Comment: @cdrrr print(str(country['CountryId']))